# Weird JavaScript operators

Tags: javascript, jquery, operators

I'm having a little problem with an operator. I have a number which is either plussed or subtracted depending on key input. The weird thing is that the operators += 1 and += 11 adds the numbers literally to the static number: 60 becomes 601 and 6011 instead of 61 and 71.

Here is the code, so take into consideration that the static number is 60:

```
switch(e.keyCode) {
    case 37:
        boxID -= 1;
        break;
    case 38:
        boxID -= 11;
        break;
    case 39:
        boxID += 1; // Becomes 601
        break;
    case 40:
        boxID += 11; // Becomes 6011
        break;
}
```

Comment: how do you define boxID?  the javascript runtime thinks it's a string

Comment: I define boxID like this where the ID is number 60 of the list item:

`var boxID = $('li.selected').attr('id');`

Comment: then follow cwolves advice var boxId = parseInt($("li.selected").attr("id"))

Comment: Nitpick: a numeric id is invalid, see http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-id

Answer (score 11):

`boxId` is a string in your case.  Convert it to a number first using `parseInt(boxId)` or just `boxId << 0`

The reason `-=` works is because it only has one function (subtract using Math), so `boxId` is cast to a number before the operation.  `+` is overloaded in JavaScript to mean "string concatenation OR Math addition", so if `boxId` is a string, it does string ops.

Comment: Remember to use the optional radix parameter and do `parseInt(boxId, 10)` instead. This prvents "010" from being treated as an octal number.